# Application closes on pressing "back". Any way to prevent it?

Tags: react-native

I used back handler from react native. But no results. Also the app (back button) works fine in debug mode but not in normal mode.

Comment: please provide more details, with things you tried already.

Comment: What do you mean by "gets close"? Did the app crashed or gone to background?

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

[BackHandler](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/backhandler.html) detect hardware button presses in `Android`, it programmatically invoke the default back button functionality to exit the app if there are no listeners or if none of the listeners return `true`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackPress);
}

handleBackPress = () => {
    return true;
}
```